# phpstorm git pull --rebase

Tags: windows, git, phpstorm

In phpstorm how do you do a `git pull --rebase`? I can't seem to find an option to do it. I would like this to be the default behavior as we are all working off the same branch.

I am doing the pull by `Version Control > Git > Pull Changes...`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the `Version Control -> Update Project` action. 
There you may choose the way of update: via merge (`git pull`) or via rebase (`git pull --rebase`) or via the default way for the current branch (it is merge by default).

The action also has more capabilities than Pull: it stashes/slelves your uncommitted changes if you have them, and restores them after update.

Comment: Where does it do the pull from?

Comment: It pulls from the tracked branch.

Comment: How do you set the tracked branch in phpstorm?

Comment: If you previously checked _Do not show this dialog in the future_ you can bring it back using `File > Settings... > Version Control > Confirmation`

Comment: @rob There is no way to modify branch tracking from PhpStorm. However, if you checkout a remote branch from PhpStorm, the tracking is set up automatically.